# Configure docker-compose.yml to use domain name instead of localhost

Tags: docker

My docker-compose.openhim.yml's content is as follows:

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
  mapper-cluster-network:
    external: true
    name: mapper-cluster-network

services:
  openhim-core:
    container_name: openhim-core
    image: jembi/openhim-core:5
    networks:
      - mapper-cluster-network
    environment:
      - mongo_url=mongodb://mapper-mongo-1:27017,mapper-mongo-2:27017,mapper-mongo-3:27017/openhim?replicaSet=mapper-mongo-set
      - mongo_atnaUrl=mongodb://mapper-mongo-1:27017,mapper-mongo-2:27017,mapper-mongo-3:27017/openhim?replicaSet=mapper-mongo-set
      - api_authenticationTypes=["token", "basic"]
      - authentication_enableCustomTokenAuthentication=true
      - authentication_enableJWTAuthentication=true
      - authentication_jwt_secretOrPublicKey=secret
      - authentication_jwt_algorithms=HS256
      - authentication_jwt_issuer=openhim
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "5000:5000"
      - "5001:5001"

  openhim-console:
    container_name: openhim-console
    image: jembi/openhim-console:1.14
    networks:
      - mapper-cluster-network
     environment:
      - OPENHIM_CORE_MEDIATOR_HOSTNAME=revamp.intelehealth.org
      - OPENHIM_MEDIATOR_API_PORT=8080
    ports:
      - "9000:80"
    depends_on:
      - openhim-core
```

However, when I am trying to access `revamp.intelehealth.org:9000` it is saying that `it is unable to connect to openhim core on https://localhost:8080.`

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuFHy.png)

I am failing to understand why is the code picking up localhost when I have exclusively given domain name. Any help will be a great help.

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your configuration is the indentation level for the environment key under the openhim-console service.
You have:

```
networks:
  - mapper-cluster-network
 environment:
  - OPENHIM_CORE_MEDIATOR_HOSTNAME=revamp.intelehealth.org
  - OPENHIM_MEDIATOR_API_PORT=8080
ports:
  - "9000:80"
```

Should be:

```
networks:
  - mapper-cluster-network
environment:
  - OPENHIM_CORE_MEDIATOR_HOSTNAME=revamp.intelehealth.org
  - OPENHIM_MEDIATOR_API_PORT=8080
ports:
  - "9000:80"
```

Comment: Hi @Slava even after correcting the indentation the error is still the same.